# Log4Net Console Appender in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, log4net, log4net-appender

I have a WPF application, where RollingFileAppender works fine in logging the messages to a log file.
However I am trying to retrieve only INFO level logs and display them in a WPF window.
I have tried with NotifyAppender, COnsole Appender, none of them works as expected .
Can anyone suggest what would be the correct approach for this, where a WPF window or console window will pop up and show the real time INFO logs .

Comment: Have tried to use [MemoryAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_MemoryAppender.htm)?

Comment: How are you configuring log4net? (programmatically or with a xml/config file?) When you are using a xml/config file, are you updating it? (Copy to outputpath if never in the attributes). If you do, have you made sure that the file is updated?

Comment: @Fildor - Yes Memory Appender .
I got my solution working following the way mentioned here . 
https://www.thepicketts.org/2012/12/how-to-watch-your-log-through-your-application-in-log4net/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter to achieve what you describe:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="INFO" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

This will show only INFO messages in a console window.

Comment: I have the same snippet in my AppConfig.
Its a WPF Application, ConsoleAppender doesn't open a console and writes the log .
I have tried will AllocConsole() as well, no luck .

Comment: Well that is a different question I guess.  You should post that separately.

Comment: Got it working using the the solution mentioned here :
https://www.thepicketts.org/2012/12/how-to-watch-your-log-through-your-application-in-log4net/